# hubot-slack "Cannot find module" - from upstart only

Tags: node.js, vagrant, node-modules, upstart, hubot

I'm following a tutorial on PluralSight regarding vagrant and hubot slack setup.

The only difference is that I'm using hubot-slack.

If I start the hubot by invoking `hubot` script from terminal - everything works fine - the bot connects and responds to commands.

Unfortunately, when the hubot is started as a service from by the upstart - I get this logged into /var/log/upstart/myhubot.log `Cannot load adapter slack - Error: Cannot find module 'hubot-slack'

my `/bin/hubot` file looks like this (this works just fine when executed from cli):

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
npm install
export PATH="node_modules:node_modules/.bin:node_modules/hubot/node_modules/.bin:$PATH"
export HUBOT_SLACK_TOKEN={}
exec node_modules/.bin/hubot --name "hubot" --adapter slack "$@"
```

my `.conf` file that's executed as a service looks like this (can't find module):

```
description "My hubot"
author "Me bla@bla.com"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

setuid vagrant

env HOME="/home/vagrant"

chdir /vagrant/my-awesome-hubot

console log

script
  export PATH="node_modules:node_modules/.bin:node_modules/hubot/node_modules/.bin:/usr/bin/coffee:/usr/bin/node:$PATH"
  export HUBOT_SLACK_TOKEN={}
  echo "DEBUG: `set`" >> /tmp/myhubot.log
  exec node_modules/.bin/hubot --name "hubot" --adapter slack
end script

respawn
```

Keep in mind that the slack token is excluded from these scripts.
Debug reveals that `chdir` does the correct thing and the `pwd` is exactly the same as when I execute the script manually.

I've tried removing entire nodejs project and generating with yeoman from scratch and also tried installing hubot-slack both globaly and localy but to no avail.

In case of a `.conf` file - there is no npm install but in the `provision.sh` file - I am cd-ing (as a vagrant user) to the root directory, doing npm install - and only then, service restart. I am also making sure to clean up everything before another round of testing before I do - `vagrant provision`

```
cp /vagrant/upstart/myhubot.conf /etc/init/myhubot.conf
sudo -u vagrant -i sh -c 'cd /vagrant/my-awesome-hubot; npm install'
service myhubot restart
```

Do you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I've just spent the day working through the same issue as this unanswered question so thought I would update with my solution.

The current hubot generated app is started with the cli with command `HUBOT_SLACK_TOKEN=xoxb-YOUR-TOKEN-HERE ./bin/hubot --adapter slack` whilst in the folder where hubot was generated. Therefore the utilises the default bin/hubot script.

Your conf file needs to pick this up therefore should run the following:

```
description "My hubot"
author "Me bla@bla.com"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

script
  chdir /vagrant/my-awesome-hubot
  export PATH="node_modules:node_modules/.bin:node_modules/hubot/node_modules/.bin:/usr/bin/coffee:/usr/bin/node:$PATH"
  HUBOT_SLACK_TOKEN=xoxb-YOUR-TOKEN-HERE ./bin/hubot --adapter slack --name "hubot" >> /tmp/myhubot.log
end script

respawn
```